# Why was my question closed as a duplicate?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I asked two questions in a day about mapping IDictionaries in Fluent NHibernate, one about using a composite-key for the index (which isn't yet supported - information gleaned through stack overflow) and another about standard mappings.

1. [Use Component as IDictionary index in AsMap in Fluent Nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252474/use-component-as-idictionary-index-in-asmap-in-fluent-nhibernate)
2. [How to map IDictionary  in Fluent NHibernate [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254176/how-to-map-idictionarystring-entity-in-fluent-nhibernate-closed)

The other question is linked from there.

The latter of these questions has been closed as a duplicate and apparently can be merged into the former. I think that this will be a very useful question to have open as it essentially documents the fluent nhibernate interface for this very frequently used object (information which is hard to come by). The other is a very specific usage of the mapping for IDictionary which I think will be useful to have the lack of availability documented for people as I spent several hours searching for it before coming to stack overflow for a definitive answer.

Both questions have answers.

Can anyone either explain why this question has been closed or vote to keep it open as I know I would have found it useful to have available when searching last week.

Comment: Looks like you got some attention. 1 vote away from being re-opened :)

Comment: What exactly will be lost if they are merged?  It appears they really do solve the same issue.  One is a bit more general, but they can both exist in the same question.  So what is the harm in either closing one, or merging them?

Comment: It's back open now.

Comment: Thanks guys.

@Pollyanna, the questions are actually very different, one documents an everyday usage of something that's actually quite hard to find documentation for on the internet - hence my eagerness to keep it simple and separate, the other is asking how to do something that sits on top of this that is a complex usage that isn't even supported yet. Having the two questions separate makes it a lot easier for people to understand - I often find simple examples a lot more useful than all-encompassing convoluted ones for the majority of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it should be re-opened.

To an outsider (someone who doesn't really know NHibernate), it looks like another example of a new user asking the same question twice instead of bumping their first question.

It's not your fault, but that's probably why it happened.

When I vote to close a question I do the following first:

1. Check the user's question history.

   - Is this question a duplicate of an earlier question they asked?
2. Check Google for `site:stackoverflow.com "searchwords"` to see if the a similar question has been asked before
3. Check the comments to see if someone has posted a duplicate, and I check that question for similarities.

Answer (score 5):

To extend [George's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39536/why-was-this-question-closed/39540#39540):

Both questions were about Fluent NHibernate, both about IDictionary, both from the same low rep user on the same day. Looking at these data statistic teaches us, that the asker (that means *you*), made a mistake and misunderstood how SO and question bumping works (see also sniperX' comment to the closed as dupe question).

There are many questions out there and many dupes. Your questions met a common dupe pattern. To avoid this trap in the future, best thing to do is to mention the first question and explaining how the new one differs.

Flag the closed one for mod attention and ask for re-opening.